# .htaccess RewriteRule not splitting where I'd like

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, rewrite

So, I'd like to turn the following url:

```
tags/tag1/tag2/tag3
```

into one that is parameterized like:

```
tags.php?tags=tag1&tags=tag2&tags=tag3
```

which has left me with the following RewriteRules (among others)

```
RewriteRule ^tags/([^/]+)(/.+)?$ tags.php?tags=$1$2 [C]
RewriteRule ^tags.php?tags=([^/]+)/([^/]+)(/.+)?$ tags.php?tags=$1&tags=$2$3 [N]
```

but when I pull up the tags variable using php I get `"tag1/tag2/tag3"`, which leads me to believe it is not running correctly. Anyone have any idea why the second rule isn't even getting applied once?

Comment: `RewriteRule` CANNOT match query string directly -- only with help of `RewriteCond`. RewriteRule matches path part of URL only (e.g. for URL `tags.php?tags=tag1&tags=tag2&tags=tag3` it will match `tags.php` part only). To work with query string use `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} regex-pattern-here` -- check docs http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond . If not sure -- enable rewrite debugging (`RewriteLogLevel 9`) and see rewrite log for details.

Comment: That's likely my issue then. Maybe I'll figure out how to write it in reverse. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up going with was:

```
RewriteRule ^tags/?$ tags.php [L]
RewriteRule ^tags/&(tags\[\]=.*)$ tags.php?$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^tags/([^/]+)(/?.*)$ tags/$2&tags[]=$1 [L]
```

Which does the same thing but builds it in reverse.

Answer (score 0):

```
# Mostly the same as your first one - tweaked to allow for the second capture
# to be empty (1 tag) and to allow for (and ignore) a trailing slash:
RewriteRule ^tags/([^/]+)(/?.*)/?$ tags.php?tags=$1$2 [C]

# Again, minor tweak, allowing a blank string in the third match so the last
# run of the mangling (when you have `tags=tags1&tags=tags2/tags3`) doesn't come
# back with no match.
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^tags=([^/]+)/([^/]+)(/?.*)$

# Match the file exactly; only happens if the condition matched (if a slash
# was found in the query params)
RewriteRule ^tags.php$ tags.php?tags=%1&tags=%2%3 [N]
```

Comment: I couldn't get this to work for me and I don't have the ability to turn on logging through my host. I still get `tag1/tag2`